# Ordinal indicator causes problems for XML parser

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, minidom

I have a Python script which parse XML from a website, so that implies that I can't touch the original XML and it looks like that:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<list>
    <orderDate>09/06/2017</orderDate>
    <orderObject>RC CAR</orderObject>
    <orderName>2ª versione</orderName>
    <orderShipped>true</orderShipped>
</list>
```

I'm facing a problem when the server answer with a XML data as above, when "orderName" contains a number with an ordinal indicator like in this case "ª" it gives me the following:

```
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token):
```

In Python side I'm using minidom as a parser with this code:

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse(order_data)
```

I want to specify that when another XML does not contain an ordinal number everything works perfectly. Thanks to whoever will help me.

Comment: have you tried encoding="ISO-8859-1"  ?

Comment: You mean in the python header, right? Yes, same problem. In XML fine I can't try this encoding because I can't control the server side.